# PHP Download from private GitHub repository

Tags: php, curl, github

I'm trying to download a private repository from GitHub using PHP. I can connect using cURL. If I try the command on console I get the .zip archive. My problem is that I don't know exactly how to do it in PHP.

I managed to connect to my private repo and I get a `Resource id #2`.

This is the cURL command:

```
curl -L -v -H "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN" https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/zipball > test.zip
```

And this is what I managed to do in PHP:

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.github.com/repos/user/repo/zipball");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");


$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Authorization: token MY_TOKEN";
$headers[] = "User-Agent: https://api.github.com/repos/user";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
print_r($ch); // This returns `Resource id #2`
curl_close ($ch);
```

How can I get/download the content from `Resource id #2` ?

Comment: what does the `$result` echo? From php manual about curl_exec: `Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on success, FALSE on failure`

Comment: If I do a `var_dump($result)` I get `string(0) ""`

Comment: try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-exec.php#119059

Comment: Same thing. Nothing changed.

Comment: you can try to add `curl_setopt ( $this -> ch , CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 1 );` for more info

Comment: I put `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE , 1);` ... nothing.

Comment: I put `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);` and not $returns some gibberish that I assume is the .zip file. Now I have to see how can I donwload that. Thank you for your help.

Comment: just save it in a file on server with the `.zip` extension (ps: Idon't know if you really need the CUSTOMREQUEST, because the default is GET - eventually you can add CURLOPT_HTTPGET)

Comment: Yes, the `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST` is useless. I managed to save it with `file_put_contents` on server. Thank you :)

Comment: Solved!
The header should not be returned.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/53858866/15045452