# Trouble using PHP curl to download github repo

Tags: php, github-api, php-curl

As per the title, I'm trying to use the php curl library to download a repo from github. Here's my code:

```
        $url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/SeanPeterson/Raspberry-Pi-Case/zipball/master';
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'SeanPeterson');
        $content = curl_exec($curl);

        if(curl_errno($curl)){
            $this->respond('error:' . curl_error($curl));
         }

        curl_close($curl);
```

The result of this code is a corrupt zip file that turns into a cpgz file when attempting to unzip. Here's the header info that exists when opening the zip file with a text editor

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Server: GitHub.com
Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2018 18:47:52 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 0
Status: 302 Found
X-RateLimit-Limit: 60
X-RateLimit-Remaining: 60
X-RateLimit-Reset: 1545248872
Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Expires: Wed, 19 Dec 2018 18:47:52 GMT
Location: https://codeload.github.com/SeanPeterson/Raspberry-Pi-Case/legacy.zip/master
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: ETag, Link, Location, Retry-After, X-GitHub-OTP, X-RateLimit-Limit, X-RateLimit-Remaining, X-RateLimit-Reset, X-OAuth-Scopes, X-Accepted-OAuth-Scopes, X-Poll-Interval, X-GitHub-Media-Type
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains; preload
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Referrer-Policy: origin-when-cross-origin, strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-GitHub-Request-Id: D01E:1971:33F0754:7030B7C:5C1A9258

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://render.githubusercontent.com
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'; style-src 'unsafe-inline'; sandbox
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Vary: Authorization,Accept-Encoding
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
ETag: "09b31138d130b657cea3c3b5e12191fa7f48c558"
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=SeanPeterson-Raspberry-Pi-Case-09b3113.zip
X-Geo-Block-List: 
Date: Wed, 19 Dec 2018 18:47:53 GMT
X-GitHub-Request-Id: D01F:77CB:DA101:20BE73:5C1A9258
```

When hitting the link with the browser, it downloads the file perfectly. So form this, I assume that I must be making a mistake with how I'm using curl.

Any insight is much appreciated!

Comment: Use guzzle: http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: Also your user agent is probably wrong: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent  

But I'd still use Guzzle instead.  It'll be easier.  Throw a composer file into your project and load the guzzle package.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, guzzle looks pretty interesting!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    $url = 'https://api.github.com/repos/SeanPeterson/Raspberry-Pi-Case/zipball/master';
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'SeanPeterson');
    $content = curl_exec($curl);


    $err = curl_error($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }

    $fp = fopen("test.zip","wb");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
```

Think you including the header is what might be corrupting the zip.

Comment: Yes, this seems obvious now. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)